# In Sublime Text, I keep experiencing accidental multiple cursors, which destroys my code

Tags: multipleselection

I'm using Windows and trying to use Sublime Text, because all the cool kids say it is awesome and I had been using Homesite from 2003.  I have a habit of leaning on the control key when I'm cutting and pasting with a mouse, and this inevitably results in unwanted multiple cursors when editing code in Sublime. I frequently end up typing something in multiple places when it is only wanted in one. I am wondering if there is some way to disable CTRL-left-mouse in Sublime Text.  Otherwise I will have to return to Homesite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` and drop in the following code to disable CTRL-Left click.  You can also assign it to a different command if you want.

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "null"
    }
]
```

Replace `Windows` with `Linux` or `OSX` according to your platform.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not seem to work. Not knowing what the params represent, I also tried button2 and button3 and various other counts with no luck.

Comment: never mind -- it worked!  i'd accidentally edited .sublime-keymap not sublime-mousemap. thanks so much!  that info wasn't anywhere!  my life is now so much better!